# Display problem with Update Panel in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, layout

I'll try to explain my problem the best I can, here goes:  I have an update panel on an ASP.NET page and a Panel server control inside it.  I have an rounded corners extender attached to the Panel server control and the extender has a solid background with a solid border.

ok....I haven't found an easy easy to position the update panel itself, so, what I end up doing is trying to position the Panel server control with CSS.  Once I do and I run the project to see the finished product, there is a big gap from where the update panel control starts and where the Panel is positioned.

What I'm wanting to know is:  What's the best way to position an UpdatePanel or regular panel so that gap that I'm talking about doesn't show up??

If anyone needs me to clarify, let me know in the comments and I'll try my best.

Comment: Could you post a code sample of your UpdatePanel and rounded corner panel? What CSS properties are you using to position the panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not saying that this is the best answer, but I was playing the same game with gaps displaying after asynchronous postbacks in an UpdatePanel earlier this week.  I had some ajax extender controls inside the UpdatePanel and I found that by moving the markup for those controls so that they were before the controls they extended in the aspx file, my gap problems went away.

Answer (score 1):

I try to keep my UpdatePanels tightly wrapped around the actual content that is needs to have the dynamic effect.

If you only have content within that panel being updated in this fashion, I'd suggest "inverting" things so that your layout is something like:

```
<Panel>
   <UpdatePanel>
      Pertinent Conent
   </UpdatePanel>
</Panel>
<RoundedCorderExtender />
```

See if that helps resolve your spacing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `RenderMode` of the update panel from Block to Inline.